# Use Regex to highlight a text in HTML generated with Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I have a vector with a tokenized text and some other vectors of regular expressions, like this:

```
text <- c("When", " ", "Claire", " ", "visited", " ", "the", " ", "Statue", " ", "of", " ", "Liberty", " ", "for", " ", "the", " ", "first", " ", "time", ",", " ", "she", " ", "instantly", " ", "admired", " ", "it", " ", "as", " ", "a", " ", "symbol", " ", "of", " ", "freedom", ".") 

green <- c("^I$", "^you$", "^he$", "^she$", "^it$", "^we$", "^they$")
blue <- c("^the$", "^a$", "^an$")
yellow <- c("ed$")
```

How can I knit an HTML using Rmarkdown with the text printed as a human-readable text with the regular expressions highlighted with different colors ?  Like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
text <- c("When", " ", "Claire", " ", "visited", " ", "the", " ", "Statue", " ", "of", " ", "Liberty", " ", "for", " ", "the", " ", "first", " ", "time", ",", " ", "she", " ", "instantly", " ", "admired", " ", "it", " ", "as", " ", "a", " ", "symbol", " ", "of", " ", "freedom", ".") 

green <- c("^I$", "^you$", "^he$", "^she$", "^it$", "^we$", "^they$")
blue <- c("^the$", "^a$", "^an$")
yellow <- c("ed$")
```

```{r}
regex <- lapply(list(lightgreen = green, cyan = blue, yellow = yellow), function(x) {
  x <- paste(x, collapse = "|")
  paste0("(", x, ")")
})
for (i in seq_along(regex)) {
  text <- gsub(regex[[i]], paste0("<span style='background-color:", names(regex)[i], "'>\\1</span>"), text)  
}
```

`r paste(text, collapse = "")`
````

[image]

Comment: Tkank you so much. It worked just as I needed.